# descargar archivo desde url con ajax y asp.net mvc 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy intentando descargar un archivo desde una url con ajax y asp.net mvc 5
este es mi controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult DownloadDocument(DownloadModel model){
   urlFile = "http://www.storage.net/data/pdf-xml/" + model.nombre.ToLower() + model.Extencion;
   //Create a stream for the file
   Stream stream = null;
   //This controls how many bytes to read at a time and send to the client
   int bytesToRead = 10000;
   // Buffer to read bytes in chunk size specified above
   byte[] buffers = new Byte[bytesToRead];
   // The number of bytes read
   try{
     //Create a WebRequest to get the file
     HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlFile);
     //Create a response for this request
     HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();
     if (fileResp.ContentLength > 0)//aquí reviso si el archivo contiene datos (existe o no)
     {
       if (fileReq.ContentLength > 0)
         fileResp.ContentLength = fileReq.ContentLength;
       //Get the Stream returned from the response
       stream = fileResp.GetResponseStream();
       // prepare the response to the client. resp is the client Response
       //var resp = HttpContext.Current.Response;
       //Indicate the type of data being sent
       Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
       //Name the file 
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + model.nombre + model.Extencion + "\"");
       Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fileResp.ContentLength.ToString());
       int length;
       do{
         // Verify that the client is connected.
         if (Response.IsClientConnected){
           // Read data into the buffer.
           length = stream.Read(buffers, 0, bytesToRead);
           // and write it out to the response's output stream
           Response.OutputStream.Write(buffers, 0, length);
           // Flush the data
           Response.Flush();
           //Clear the buffer
           buffers = new Byte[bytesToRead];
         }else{
           // cancel the download if client has disconnected
           length = -1;
         }
       } while (length > 0); //Repeat until no data is read
     }
   }catch (Exception e){
     d2.Add("Error", e.Message);
   }finally{
     if (stream != null){
       //Close the input stream
       stream.Close();
     }else if (d2.Count < 1){
       d2.Add("Error", "El Archivo no existe");
     }
   }
   //mostramso el mensaje de que no existe el archivo
   return Json(serializer.Serialize(d2));
 }
```

Si se dirige el form al controlador realiza la descarga, pero si un archivo no existiera me mandaría en mensaje el cual yo lo muestro en mi vista pero este se muestra en una vista aparte.
Y yo quiero que se realice la descarga por medio de ajax de jquery ya que así es la manera que puedo mostrar el mensaje, pero no me aparece la descarga en el navegador
Este es mi formulario:

```
<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="formDownload" id="formDownload140464">
  <input type="hidden" value="AAA010101AAA" id="rfcCompany" name="rfcCompany">
  <input type="hidden" value="40464" id="id" name="id">
  <input type="hidden" value=".pdf" id="Extencion" name="Extencion">
  <input id="Nombre" name="Nombre">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm previewPopover" title="Descargar" onclick="MostrarMensaje(40464)">
    <span class="elusive icon-download-alt"></span>
  </button>
</form>
```

Mi funcion ajax es esta, la utilizo para mostrar el mensaje.

```
function MostrarMensaje(id) {
    $('#formDownload1' + id).on("submit", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Portal/DownloadDocument',
            data: $('#formDownload1' + id).serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var d = JSON.parse(data);
                $.jGrowl("" + d["Error"], {
                    header: "Error",
                    //sticky: true,
                    theme: "red"
                });
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Con esto se muestra el mensaje pero no me realiza la descarga.
He visto que muchos le pasan la url en el data y hacen la descarga con `window.location.href = d["Url"];`, pero mi problema aquí con este código es que no voy a saber si existe o no el archivo y me descargara un archivo vació.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No puedes abrir el diálogo de descarga del navegador desde JavaScript. Tienes que realizar una navegación al documento para que el navegador abra el diálogo de descarga.

Si quieres comprobar previamente si el archivo existe lo que puedes hacer es una acción que compruebe la existencia del archivo. De esta forma llamas a la acción a través de ajax para comprobar que el archivo existe y, si es así, realizas la navegación hacia la url de descarga con document.location.

Otra alternativa para abrir el diálogo de descargas es el atributo download de HTML5 que permite crear un link que realiza la descarga de un archivo pero no se ajustaría a tu caso y además todavía no está soportado por todos los navegadores. Sí que lo soportan Chrome, Firefox, Edge y Opera, pero no Internet Explorer en ninguna de sus versiones y si no recuerdo mal tampoco Safari.

Comment: Viendo tu respuesta la unica forma que se me ocurre para solucionar mi problema seria dejando el controlador asi: ` urlFile = "http://www.storage.net/data/pdf-xml/" + model.nombre.ToLower() + model.Extencion;try{HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlFile);HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();if fileResp.ContentLength > 0){d2.Add("Url", urlFile);}else{d2.Add("Error", "El Archivo no existe");}}catch (Exception e){d2.Add("Error", e.Message);}`

Comment: quitando todo el contenido que hace la descarga y dejando unicamente estas lineas `HttpWebRequest fileReq = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(urlFile);` y `HttpWebResponse fileResp = (HttpWebResponse)fileReq.GetResponse();`

Comment: Esa sería la idea. Comprobar vía Ajax si el archivo existe y, si es así, realizar la redirección para que se realice la descarga.

Answer (score 0):

Noe s valido enviar un array de byte como json para realizar la descarga, sino que lo envias como file

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult DownloadDocument(DownloadModel model){
  //resto codigo
  return File(...)
}
```

[ASP.NET MVC Uploading and Downloading Files](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/125/asp-net-mvc-uploading-and-downloading-files)

y usas una libreria como ser

[jquery.fileDownload](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)

para realizar la descarga usando javascript

Comment: Pero la librería jquery.fileDownload al final lo que hace es crear un iframe oculto y utilizar el location del iframe para generar la descarga lo que viene a ser lo mismo. Además utiliza cookies lo que me parece añadir un requisito innecesario.